# Vim: open files of the matches on the lines given by Grep?

Tags: vim, grep

I want to get automatically to the positions of the results in Vim after grepping, on command line. Is there such feature?

**Files to open in Vim on the lines given by grep:**

```
% grep --colour -n checkWordInFile *
SearchToUser.java:170:  public boolean checkWordInFile(String word, File file) {
SearchToUser.java~:17:  public boolean checkWordInFile(String word, File file) {
SearchToUser.java~:41:          if(checkWordInFile(word, f))
```

Comment: what's wrong with `:grep` and the quick fix buffer (`:copen`)?

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminBannier how do you use `:copen` with `git grep`?

Comment: @PaulRougieux In general see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115534/vim-redirect-output-to-quickfix, but for `git grep` I personally would go with https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt#L91 (and even for other shell commands I'd probably use https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at "[Grep search tools integration with Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311)" and "[Find in files within Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim)". Basically vim provides these commands for searching files:

```
:grep
:lgrep
:vimgrep
:lvimgrep
```

The articles feature more information regarding their usage.

Answer (score 29):

If you pipe the output from `grep` into `vim`

```
% grep -n checkWordInFile * | vim -
```

you can put the cursor on the filename and hit `gF` to jump to the line in that file that's referenced by that line of grep output.  `^WF` will open it in a new window.

From within vim you can do the same thing with

```
:tabedit
:r !grep -n checkWordInFile *
```

which is equivalent to but less convenient than

```
:lgrep checkWordInFile *
:lopen
```

which brings up the superfantastic quickfix window so you can conveniently browse through search results.

You can alternatively get slower but in-some-ways-more-flexible results by using vim's native grep:

```
:lvimgrep checkWordInFile *
:lopen
```

This one uses vim REs and paths (eg allowing **).  It can take 2-4 times longer to run (maybe more), but you get to use fancy `\(\)\@<=`s and birds of a feather.

Comment: :lp, :lnf to browse in quickfix list. If :grep, then use :cn and :cp. Cannot see any difference btw :lgrep and grep, instead of different moving commands.

Comment: :lopen for :lgrep and :copen for :grep.

Comment: lgrep creates a separate list for the current tab.  Otherwise you end up clobbering the same global list if you do `:grep`s from different tabs.  At least I think so; I usually use `lvimgrep` or `r !grep...` and just added `:lgrep` in here for the sake of completeness.  I guess `*open` is not really within the scope of the question actually, that's just how I usually roll.

Comment: err actually it's for the current window, not tab.

Comment: hnnnnngggghhhh incredible!

Comment: *put the cursor on the filename and hit `gF`* --> doesn't work for me.. Any configuration to enable this? 
I don't see result by using these commands. Any specific vim version for this? I am using VIM8

Comment: Pressing gf reading this way from stdin, I had an error `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)` , however I overcame it by a readonly flag -R https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2728/11459 , `% grep -n checkWordInFile * | vim -R -`

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
% vim "+/checkWordInFile" $(grep -l checkWordInFile *)
```

This will put in the vim command line a list of all the files that match the regex.  The "+/..." option will tell vim to search from the start of each file until it finds the first line that matches the regex.

**Correction:**

The +/... option will only search the first file for the regex.  To search in every file you need this:

```
% vim "-c bufdo /checkWordInFile" $(grep -l checkWordInFile *)
```

If this is something you need to do often you could write a bash function so that you only need to specify the regex once (assuming that the regex is valid for both grep and vim).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184

> When you open a file:line, for instance when coping and pasting from an error from your compiler **(or grep output)** vim tries to open a file with a colon in its name. With this little script in your plugins folder if the stuff after the colon is a number and a file exists with the name especified before the colon vim will open this file and take you to the line you wished in the first place.

It's definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend ack.vim over grep for this functionality.

http://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim

http://betterthangrep.com/

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to make functions for these. :)

### Sequential `vim` calls (console)

```sh
grep -rn "implements" app | # Or any (with "-n") you like
  awk '{
    split($0,a,":"); # split on ":"
    print "</dev/tty vim", a[1], "+" a[2] # results in lines with "</dev/tty vim <foundfile> +<linenumber>
  }' |
  parallel --halt-on-error 1 -j1 --tty bash -ec # halt on error and "-e" important to make it possible to quit in the middle
```

Use `:cq` from `vim` to stop editing.

### Concurrent opening in tabs (`gvim`)

Start the server:

```sh
gvim --servername GVIM
```

Open the tabs:

```sh
grep -rn "implements" app | # again, any grep you like (with "-n")
  awk "{ # double quotes because of $PWD
    split(\$0,a,\":\"); # split on ":"
    print \":tabedit $PWD/\" a[1] \"<CR>\" a[2] \"G\" # Vim commands. Open file, then jump to line
  }" | 
  parallel gvim --servername GVIM --remote-send # of course the servername needs to match
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use git, results are often more meaningful when you search only in the files tracked by git. To open files at the given line which is a search result of `git grep` in vim you will need the [fugitive plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt#L91), then

```
:copen
:Ggrep pattern
```

Will give you the list in a buffer and you can choose to open files from your git grep results.

Answer (score -3):

In this particular example:

```
vim SearchToUser.java +170
```