# vim redirect output to quickfix

Tags: vim, macvim

Is it possible to redirect an output of a command to the quick fix window?

The command I am running is

```
:!java %:r
```

and was hoping the output would go into the quickfix window

Comment: Could you give us more details of why you want to use quickfix list? It has a fairly specific purpose...

Comment: The line above runs some java code and ideally I would like the output of the program to redirect to quickfix window

Comment: `setqflist` + `setloclist` + `set modifiable`. give full programmatic control, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22737278/895245 and https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/7c0578d6e84384c280a714b99d7ec08c3d45cda9/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L298

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please note that the quickfix window is for specific output (e.g. of compiler or syntax checker tools) which includes references (i.e. line and column numbers) to the current buffer. There's a lot of infrastructure around this: `'makeprg'`, `'errorformat'`, etc., usually bundled into a *compiler plugin*.

Though you can redirect arbitrary output into the quickfix window, it provides little benefit (and has the downside of clobbering `'makeprg'`) over reading the output of an external program into a new scratch buffer, e.g. like this:

```
:new|0read !java #:r
```

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest one of two options: configure `makeprg` to run java like you want, or create a mapping or command to populate the quickfix list without changing anything else.

### Option 1: Using `makeprg` and compiler plugins

I would generally set the `makeprg` option for this, as others have said. It's not a hack, that's exactly what the `makeprg` option is for.

The only problem is if you have another build script you want to run as well. A more general solution is to create a simple compiler plugin. For instance, somewhere on your `runtimepath`, you can create a file under `compiler/java.vim` and set it to something like this:

```
if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = "java"

CompilerSet makeprg=java
```

Now when you're working with java, you can do `:compiler java` and then your `makeprg` will be set as desired in the *current window*. If you want to use it for all windows, use `:compiler! java`, with a bang. Not all compiler plugins set the `makeprg` option, but you can always reset it with `:set makeprg&`. Try `:help write-compiler-plugin` for more information.

### Option 2: Create a command to do it

Alternatively, you can also use `cexpr` to populate the quickfix list. For instance:

```
:cexpr system('java ' . shellescape(expand('%:r')))
```

The `expand` is necessary to expand the `'%:r'` in an expression, and `shellescape` escapes it so it can be used as an argument to a shell command. Then the string `'java '` is prepended to the escaped path and the result is invoked as a shell command by `system`. The output from this command is used to load the quickfix list.

The nice thing about this is that it doesn't change `makeprg` or any other settings, but still lets you easily populate the quickfix list. Of course, you'll probably want to map this or define a custom command for it.

Comment: Just wanna say hat option 2 is definitely what I was looking for, and it's surprisingly difficult to search for. So kudos.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. `set makeprg=java`
2. `make %:r`

It's a bit of hack, and of course assumes you aren't already using `makeprg` for your actual build script.

Answer (score 0):

I mapped leader + j + r to run my java code and display it in the quickfix window by doing

```
map <leader>jr :set makeprg=java <CR>:make %:r<CR>:copen<CR>
```