# Need a tool for exploring stacktrace frames

Tags: linux, stack-trace, curses

I commonly wind up trouble-shooting web apps written in varied languages, located on heterogeneous servers that aren't mine.  I'm often in the situation of having a stacktrace from a log file, and wanting to explore the code associated with it.

Despite the many varied forms, there's a pretty strong convention that each line of the stacktrace represents one call deeper or shallower in the calling stack, and each has something in it that looks like `directory/path/file.ext:linenumber`.  The path might be absolute, but just as likely is relative to some base folder for the app.

I need a tool or a technique that doesn't require a lot of installation that will allow me to click back and forth between the code locations referred to in the stacktrace.  Maybe it's just a way of munging things into a command line for less or vim or some such?  Unfortunately while I can easily give a list of files on the command line, I don't know a way to specify a list of positions in those files.

Any suggestions?

Ideally this should involve installing as little as possible.  Mostly I'm on Debian and Ubuntu servers, but sometimes Redhat or Centos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is basically the output format from `grep -n`, which some text-editors understand — and allow you to walk though the matches.

- emacs does this, [of course](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode)
- vim does (see for example *[Vim: open files of the matches on the lines given by Grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653419/vim-open-files-of-the-matches-on-the-lines-given-by-grep)*)
- vile does (as part of the [error-buffer](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile-hlp.html#misc-commands)).